How do I get a GoogleSignInAccount on Android?
I know all of the code steps I need to do this (getting a GoogleSignIn client, etc). In fact I had it working in the past, but it doesn't work now.
At the point where I get the account by calling getResult on the GoogleSignInResult task, an exception is thrown (com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10).
I believe that the problem lies somewhere in how the Firebase and/or Google Cloud project for the app is set up. Here's what I have:
First, I have an OAuth 2 Client ID set up in Google Cloud Console. The package name matches my app, and the SHA-1 fingerprint matches my debug certificate since I'm trying to test it with debug builds.
I also have my app in a Firebase project. Since Firebase allows you to put more than one fingerprint, I added both fingerprints from both my debug and release certificates. Then I downloaded the google-services.json file and put it in my project.
I think this should be all I need. I do get a system dialog asking me to pick an account. The exception happens after that.
Thanks.

You should post the relevant code, and provide a MVCE
